# When should $scope.apply() be used in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

What does $scope.apply do? In some cases, if $scope.apply() is not present, $scope.watch() is not triggered. For example,

The controller has the following:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $scope.person = someperson;
}, 500);
```

person is being watched in the directive.

```
$scope.watch('person', function(){
  console.log($scope.person);
  $scope.apply();
});
```

In this case, watch is triggered only when apply is there.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

Answer (score 1):

If you modify an AngularJS model outside (from external JavaScript) - you should use $scope.$apply() to let AngularJS know that model has changed. In your example you use setTimeout() which is an async external js method. However if you use the AngularJS $timeout you wont need to call $scope.$apply().

Answer (score 1):

**$scope.apply()** will trigger the **$digest** loop of AngularJS. To put is simple, it's just a convenient way to trigger the app rerender.

Usually it is used when you want to run a piece of code that is outside of angular app.

Direct from the documentation:

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

Example of using scope.$apply() with jQuery Datepicker:

```
angular.module('customApp', []).directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            jQuery(element).datepicker({
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.myDate = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(function(){}`:-It is javascript function which is out of the scope of anuglar js you need to manually apply the digest cycle with the help of  $scope.apply();

But instead you can use $timeout service which is more angular way.